# Is $\sum_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_L=k}\binom{1}{n_1}\binom{2}{n_2}\binom{3}{n_3}\cdots\binom{L}{n_L}=\sum_{q=0}^{T_{L-1}}\binom{T_{L-1}}{q}\binom{L}{k-q} $?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, binomial-coefficients

A few days back, I was playing around with the product $$\prod_{n=1}^L (1-x^n) $$ I tried to expand it using a probability argument, i.e. by considering $1-x^n$ as the probability of atleast one *success* among $n$ trials and so on. Then on attempting to find the coefficient of $x$ to some power, I was faced by the hurdle of evaluating $$S(L,k)= \sum_{n_1+n_2+\cdots+n_L=k}\binom{1}{n_1}\binom{2}{n_2}\binom{3}{n_3}\cdots\binom{L}{n_L} $$ where $n_i$ cannot exceed $i$ and $k\le T_L = \frac{L(L+1)}{2}$.

By fixing $L=1,2,3$, I saw that this could be written as something like $$ \sum a_q \binom{L}{k-q} $$ and further that $a_q$ were exactly the binomial coefficients of $T_{L-1}$, so that the original sum equals $$ \sum_{q=0}^{T_{L-1}}\binom{T_{L-1}}{q}\binom{L}{k-q} $$

Is there any way to prove/disprove this? I’ve verified it for $k=1,2,3$ and any $L$.

It can also be seen that $$S(L+1,k) =\sum_{n=0}^k \binom{L+1}{n} S(L,k-n) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, on one side, you are taking at most $i$ elements of type $i$ when you do $\binom{i}{n_i}$. On the other side, you are placing every single element like this
$$1\underbrace{22}_{2}\underbrace{333}_{3}4444\underbrace{55555}_{5}\cdots \underbrace{(L-1)(L-1)(L-1)\cdots (L-1)(L-1)}_{L-1\text{ times}}$$
So there are $T_{L-1}$ elements in that string. You are taking $q$ of them and if you take this $q$ and describe $n_i:=\text{The number of times you took an element i from the q}$ then $n_i\leq i$. This can be done in $\binom{T_{L-1}}{q}$ ways and multiplying by $\binom{L}{k-q}$ by means of the product rule, just means adding to this scheme the number of times you took $L$.
This argument let you say further that your expression is actually $$\binom{T_L}{k}.$$

Comment: So simple, yet I made a big deal about it.

Comment: @Tavish Been there, almost daily.

Comment: One more question, do you know how to evaluate the sum if instead $n_i\ge 1$?

Comment: @Tavish Try using exclusion exclusion. You exclude missing one of the classes.

Comment: Counting terms when, say, $t$ of $n_i$ are zero turns out to be quite difficult. It involves partitions of a number or something I guess.

Comment: @Tavish I agree, I get something like
$$\sum _{S\subseteq [L]}(-1)^{|S|}\binom{L}{|S|}\binom{T_L-w(S)}{k},$$
where $w(S)$ is the sum of elements in $S$. Usually one goes to $q-$analogs to deal with these weight, but you come from there.